# Where do I put JS files that are missing in dotCMS?

Tags: dotcms

I set up a new install of dotCMS to research for possible deployment. The initial demo site that comes with it did not work, so I extracted the starter zip file and moved the assets to the asset folder in dotCMS. Going to the index page, flexslider is not found. Where do I put this file within the dotCMS directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are building new sites in dotcms you can basically build the site the way you like. Dotcms does not force any directory structure on you, it's up to you. In this case however you have an existing site that is missing one file which means that you should put the file in the directoty that the html expects it to be. You should open the site and look at fhe source html (ctrl-u in most browsers). Look for the script tag that tries to include the file that is missing and check what the directory is. Put the file in that directory. Remember that you cannot put the file in the dotcms directory on the disk (like with wordpress), because dotcms uses a virtual folder structure. You must use the admin to upload the file or use webdav to mount the virtual directory structure to your file system.